# C# Ascii to bytes, parsing not conversion

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, ascii

I have a windows form where you can input text in one textbox, and it outputs the conversion in the other textbox. I have various conversions.

say I input "hello world"

my ascii to bytes function gives me back: 10410110810811132119111114108100

all is good. now I need to use my bytes to ascii function to convert it back.

the problem is that

```
byte[] b;  
b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext); //it is a string from the textbox
```

OK, MOSTLY SOLVED, BUT, the problem still remains, input "1101000 1100101" as a string, parse as bytes/ byte array, and then get a string out of it. (I know the last part)

Comment: If a question is marked as duplicate it means that another answer will answer your question. So there is no need to have hundreds of questions being the same.

Comment: that makes sense, but then when I goto ask a question, it says you are in danger of being blocked. I have had one bad question, and only asked 2 in total.

Comment: One byte can represent a number between 0 and 255. Your string is a concatenation of such numbers: 104, 101, 108, 108, 111 for the "hello".

Comment: Before you ask a question, research on SO if it has already been asked and its answer solves your problem.  This'll prevent your questions from being marked as duplicates.  When you ask a question you need to provide at least what your problem is, efforts you have already tried (code sample) to solve the problem, possible inputs and expected results.  Otherwise, you run risks of getting down voted and being blocked.  Read this to help you post "better" questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I do research. I ask a question as a last resort. the one on reflection I had look for about an hour for an answer. I just didn't have the right terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

From binary input string to ASCII string

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100";
        string[] binary = input.Split(' ');

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", binary.Select(b => Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(b, 2))).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
hello world
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rovnuC)

### OLD ANSWER

So now it sounds like you want to convert your string to binary and then from binary back to a string.  From my OLD ANSWER, you can use the `Select()` (LINQ) statement to convert your string to a binary string array.

Once you have a binary string array, to convert it back you have to convert each element to a `byte` from base 2, then convert the `byte` to a `char` resulting in a `char[]`, from which can be converting back to a `string`.  No padding is necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "hello world";
        byte[] inputBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

        // Decimal display
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", inputBytes));

        // Hex display
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", inputBytes.Select(ib => ib.ToString("X2"))));

        // Binary display
        string[] binary = inputBytes.Select(ib => Convert.ToString(ib, 2)).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", binary));

        // Converting bytes back to string
        Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length));

        // Binary to ASCII (This is what you're looking for)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", binary.Select(b => Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(b, 2)))));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64
1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
hello world
hello world
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqwL7p)

Comment: here is the problem, say now I unput "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100" as a string, I need it to parse as binary, then convert it back to Ascii, not get the binary representation of _that_ string

Comment: **So now it sounds like you want to convert your string to binary and then from binary back to a string.**  

No, I want to parse the string as binary  
input string = "10101001"  
return what that is as ascii.  
You have made a very well thought out and good answer, but my problem is, I need to parse it, like the title says. not just convert it.

Comment: What are you wanting when you say "parse"? If you input is a binary string that looks like "1101000 1100101".  "1101000" from binary to decimal is 104 and 104 is the decimal value for the letter 'h'.  "1100101" from binary to decimal is 101 and 101 is the decimal value for the letter 'e'.

Comment: because when I do what you have in code, it converts whatever binary I have in the string, back to a string containing the same binary

Comment: @DOSLuke From the link, you're input is a binary string so you don't even need the first two lines that make a binary array. You need to split the string by a single space then do the Binary to ASCII. See updated answer.

Comment: well, after a fair amount of us not understanding each other and my c# inexperience, it works. thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse to `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)` is `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes[])`:

```
string plaintext = "hello world";
byte[] b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
Console.WriteLine(b); // new bytes[] { 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100 }
string s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
Console.WriteLine(s); // "hello world"
```

> how the heck does `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world")` give me back `10410110810811132119111114108100`?! that's not binary!

It does not give you that number. It gives you a byte array; an array of bytes. And a `byte` is a number between 0 and 255 (which can be stored in one byte, hence them name). What did you expect? A **string** containing only `1` and `0` characters? That’s not binary either; that’s a string.

You can use `Convert.ToString` to get a binary string from a single byte:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(104, 2)); // "1101000"
```

Note that you need to left-pad those strings to make them use 8 characters.

Comment: btw, I was expecting back a byte array: {1101000, 1100101}

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer, a byte is a number between 0 and 255 that takes a byte in memory. What you were expecting would be an array of strings that contain the number in binary. You will have to convert that as described though.